# How does R store Milliseconds in a Date-Time Object?

Tags: r, datetime, xts

I'm just a bit curious as to how R stores milliseconds in a date-time object since some odd things happen when I try and look at a few properties of datetime objects.

Let's say for instance I have a date-time object as follows:

```
 t1<- as.POSIXct("2007-05-04 16:04:53.912", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS") + 1e-6

 t2<- as.POSIXct("2007-05-04 16:04:53.911", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS") + 1e-6
```

Now, if I were to check:

```
 t1 == t2
```

Then R outputs `FALSE`, since the millisecond values between `t1` and `t2` differ from each other.

However, if I now write `as.numeric(t1)` and `as.numeric(t2)` then I get the number `1178258694` for both of them, but if I instead write `as.numeric(t1) == as.numeric(t2)` then R still outputs `FALSE` despite the fact that I get the number `1178258694` for both datetime objects.

Similarly, if I convert it to an `xts` object using the code below

```
 t3 <- c(t1,t2)
 v6 <- data.frame(t3,v5)
 v7 <- xts(v6,order.by=t3)
```

Then if I now write `.index(v7)[1] == .index(v7)[2]` I get the exact same result.

Can anyone tell me why, despite the fact `as.numeric(t1)` equals `1178258694` and `as.numeric(t2)` equals `1178258694`, `as.numeric(t1)` does not equal `as.numeric(t2)`?

EDIT: I'm mainly asking because I would like to perform a 'check' using the numerical values of a datetime object since R appears to work with those values more efficiently compared to the standard datetime object

Comment: Try `print(as.numeric(t1), digits = 20)` (or some other large number) & you'll see that the `as.numeric()` doesn't return the same result for t1 & t2, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [R documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/DateTimeClasses.html),

> Date-Time class POSIXct represents the number of seconds since the
>   beginning of 1970 as a numeric vector

The key part is the use of a numeric vector, which allows for decimal representations. Try printing t1 or t2 in a different format and you will see how it is an actual number.

```
sprintf("%f", t1) #[1] "1178319893.912001"
sprintf("%f", t2) #[1] "1178319893.911001"
```

What you see as a result of `as.numeric` is just the format it spits out. You could print the result of `as.numeric(t1)` the same way as above and it will show the decimals too.

Comment: Thanks for that! So just one last quick question, would it be safe to perform a "check" such as `as.numeric(t1) == as.numeric(t2)` in an IF statement? Would it always be able to differentiate between the two values? I just want to make sure it's completely foolproof

Comment: Yes, you can even do `t1==t2` if what you need is to check whether 2 timestamps are exactly the same value.